# Render `.excalidraw` file in `README.md`

Tags: markdown, figure

I have created an [Excalidraw](https://github.com/excalidraw/excalidraw) figure and saved it as a `.excalidraw` file. To render the figure in GitLab, it is possible to open the file in an editor and then paste the code into the `README.md` as

````
```excalidraw

// excalidraw code

```
````

However, Excalidraw produces a large amount of code, and the code is pretty unreadable, which makes the `README.md` messy.

Is there a way to include the render the `.excalidraw` file directly? More precisely, can I add the `.excalidraw` file to the project and then render with something like

````
```excalidraw

myFigure.excalidraw

```
````

Comment: You'd have better luck making this a github issue / feature request. AFAIK, it's not possible, and this issue is the closest thing to it https://github.com/excalidraw/excalidraw/issues/1090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the [Excalidraw Visusal Studio Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pomdtr.excalidraw-editor). It lets you create `.excalidraw.svg` and `.excalidraw.png` files.

When you create the file with the `.excalidraw.png` extension like below:

```
myFigure.excalidraw.png
```

You get a file that is both editable in the excalidraw editor *and* it contains the PNG bits to reference it in your markdown.

Like any other image you can then reference it in your `readme.md` markdown file as:

```
![My figure](myFigure.excalidraw.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless gitlab adds support to render `.excalidraw`-content, you cannot.

However, you are be able to export it as SVG/PNG and include the scene data in the file. With this approach, you have a nicely rendered Markdown file, because you just include an image, and you are also able to edit the image/scene again with excalidraw.

Top right Corner: "Save as image" -> Tick "Embed Scene" -> Save as PNG/SVG.

[Screenshot of excalidraw: Save as image with scene data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAs7e.png)